# How to solve a linear programming problem

Tags: linear-programming

Given a problem (D, c, Min) with admissible set
D={(x,y)∈R2 : |y+√3x|≤2√3,|y-√3x|≤2√3,|y|≤3}
and the price function c(x, y) = x + 2y.
Translate the given problem to a linear program in standard form. Determine the corresponding matrix A and the vectors ⃗b and ⃗c respectively.

Comment: Hi Klara! Welcome to CS stack exchange. The community helps those who help themselves first. Please show what effort you made by yourself and where you got stuck. Then, the community would be glad to help!

Comment: Also tell us which standard form you have to use, precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Your main goal here is to rewrite your constraints as **linear constraints**. There is a good ressource to do such a translation [here](https://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.1/absolute.htm).

You're lucky here as your constraints are of the form $|L| \leq C$ where $L$ is a linear combination of your variables and $C$ a constant. It simply can be written as two linear constraints :
$$ |L| \leq C \iff
\begin{cases}
L \leq C \\
-L \leq C
\end{cases}
$$

For example, you can rewrite one of your constraints as :

$$
\left|y + \sqrt3 x \right| \leq 2 \iff 
     \begin{cases}
      y + \sqrt3 x \leq 2 \\
      - y - \sqrt3 x \leq 2
    \end{cases} 
$$

I think you can do the other constraints now. Good luck!